# writing a query for table and giving a score

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query for the following:

Count the number of transactions in the previous 90 days. Note: This needs to be averaged out for new members = (No of transactions / Days being a member) x 90

New members are the one whose DateCreated is between 0 and 90 days from todays date.

Table structure:

```
 Column Name         Datatype
---------------------------------
Member_No           nvarchar(255)
Order_No            int
Transaction_Date    datetime 
Net                 money
Date_Created        datetime
```

Also, the final step is after counting the transactions, I need to give a score. So if a member has count more than 8 then give a score of 5.

Following are the ranges:`

```
Transaction count      Score
  >8                  5
  6-8                 4
  4-6                 3
  2-4                 2
  0-2                 1
```

Sample Data:

```
Member No   Sales Order Number  Date Created    Transaction Date    Net
M1                2332            01-10-15       10-07-16           354
M2                2311            12-12-16       14-12-16           53
M3                5422            04-10-14       07-10-14           35
M5                4535            10-10-16       12-11-16           54
M9                5522            03-05-15       07-10-15           55
M3                5422            04-10-14       02-12-16           83
M5                4534            10-10-16       13-12-16           73
M3                5432            04-10-14       09-10-14           35
M3                5484            04-10-14       11-10-16           34
M3                5453            04-10-14       07-11-16           67
M3                5474            04-10-14       09-11-16           56
M3                5493            04-10-14       07-12-16           52
M3                5452            04-10-14       10-12-16           75
M3                5496            04-10-14       11-12-16           34
M3                5442            04-10-14       13-12-16           90
M3                5494            04-10-14       14-12-16           757
M3                5464            04-10-14       16-12-16           72
M5                4542            10-10-16       15-12-16           76
M5                4502            10-10-16       17-12-16           72
M5                4535            10-10-16       18-12-16           43
```

Output:

```
Member No   Order Count (In last 90 days)   Score
  M1                    0                      1
  M2                   10                      5
  M3                    9                      5
  M5                    5                      3
  M9                    0                      1
```

[Note:

> M1 is 0 because the DateCreated is less than 90 days from todays date (not a new member) and the member hasn't transacted in last 90
>   days
>
> M2 order count is 10 because the DaetCreated is within 90 days from todays date (new member), also transaction date falls within 90
>   days so apply the formula (No of
>         transactions / Days being a member) x 90)  = (1/10)*90 = 10 which is ordercount > 8+ hence score of 5.
>
> M3 order count is 9 as the member has transacted 9 times in last 90 days.    So score of 5.
>
> M5 order count is 5 because the DaetCreated is within 90 days from todays date (new member), also his transaction date falls within
>   90 days so apply the formula (No of transactions / Days being a
>   member) x 90)  = (4/72)*90 = 5 which is ordercount in range 4-6 hence
>   score of 3.

Let me know if any queries.

Comment: no, its not an assignment

Comment: So you want to `COUNT(*)` from your table, `GROUP BY` your member number, `WHERE` the date created is within the last 90 days, then you want to check each `CASE` of `COUNT(*)`, I'm guessing.

Comment: yeah almost, and those who don't fit,give them one as a score...Thats the main crackdown I believe

Comment: @ZLK wow it's like you're almost `PRINT` ing the solution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a basic aggregation query, with some additional logic:

```
select memberno,
       order_count_90_days,
       (case when days_ago_start >= 90
             then (case when order_count_90_days > 8 then 5
                        when order_count_90_days > 6 then 4
                        when order_count_90_days > 4 then 3
                        when order_count_90_days > 2 then 2
                        else 1
                   end)
             else (case when (order_count_90_days * 90.0 / days_ago_start) > 8 then 5
                        when (order_count_90_days * 90.0 / days_ago_start) > 6 then 4
                        when (order_count_90_days * 90.0 / days_ago_start) > 4 then 3
                        when (order_count_90_days * 90.0 / days_ago_start) > 2 then 2
                        else 1
                   end)
        end) as score                
from (select memberno,
             datediff(day, min(transactiondate), getdate()) as days_ago_start,
             sum(case when transactiondate >= getdate() - 90 then 1 else 0 end) as order_count_90_days
      from sample
      group by memberno
     ) m;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is entirely untested, but should at least give you an idea of the process that you could follow to get it working.

I suggest you get each step executing and try to understand what they do and how.

Step one: count transactions in the last 90 days.

```
select Member_No, count(Order_No) as TransactionCount
from Sales
where datediff(day, Transaction_Date, getdate()) <= 90
group by Member_No
```

Step two: get start date and age per member

```
select 
    Member_No, 
    min(Date_Created) as Date_Created, 
    datediff(day, min(Date_Created), getdate()) as Days_Old
from Sales
group by Member_No
```

Step three: combine the above

```
select *
from (
    select 
        Member_No, 
        min(Date_Created) as Date_Created, 
        datediff(day, min(Date_Created), getdate()) as Days_Old
    from Sales
    group by Member_No
) dc
join (
    select Member_No, count(Order_No) as TransactionCount
    from Sales
    where datediff(day, Transaction_Date, getdate()) <= 90
) tc on tc.Member_No=dc.Member_No
```

Step four: Pro-rate transaction count for new members

```
select 
    Member_No,
    case when dc.Days_Old > 90 
        then tc.Transaction_Count
        else tc.Transaction_Count * 90 / dc.Days_Old
    end as Transaction_Count        
from (
    select 
        Member_No, 
        min(Date_Created) as Date_Created, 
        datediff(day, min(Date_Created), getdate()) as Days_Old
    from Sales
    group by Member_No
) dc
join (
    select Member_No, count(Order_No) as TransactionCount
    from Sales
    where datediff(day, Transaction_Date, getdate()) <= 90
) tc on tc.Member_No=dc.Member_No
```

Step five, add a score based on transaction count (note that I changed your score table so that it doesn't overlap):

```
select
    *,
    case 
        when x.Transaction_Count > 8 then 5
        when x.Transaction_Count between 6 and 7 then 4
        when x.Transaction_Count between 4 and 5 then 3
        when x.Transaction_Count between 2 and 3 then 2
        else 1
    end as Score
from (
    select 
        Member_No,
        case when dc.Days_Old > 90 
            then tc.Transaction_Count
            else tc.Transaction_Count * 90 / dc.Days_Old
        end as Transaction_Count        
    from (
        select 
            Member_No, 
            min(Date_Created) as Date_Created, 
            datediff(day, min(Date_Created), getdate()) as Days_Old
        from Sales
        group by Member_No
    ) dc
    join (
        select Member_No, count(Order_No) as TransactionCount
        from Sales
        where datediff(day, Transaction_Date, getdate()) <= 90
    ) tc on tc.Member_No=dc.Member_No
) x
```

Comment: Just a small change in it as I had stated in the original query, the transaction count of 0 should be given a score of 1. 0 is given as transaction count when the members haven't transacted in the last 90 days.

Comment: Oh, and I just noticed a division by zero bug for members who are zero days old